# Why the code stops before its expected completion

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm using the following function to get a scraping job that starts at `9 AM` and expected to stop at `4 PM`. But it stops much before that, contrary to what I expect it to do. 
Let's say the scraping job is run at `t=1` and it finishes at `t=T`. If `T < 1 sec`, then it sleeps for `(1-T) sec`. After the sleep, it repeats the scrape cycle. The loop starts at `9 AM` and supposed to stop at `4 PM`.

With the `nosleep = False` it doesn't terminate immediately, instead it runs for sometime, eventually not writing any new data to `csv`, though the function doesn't exit.

If I remove the sleeping for `(1-T) sec` by setting `nosleep = True` then it runs fine.

Please let me know what is going wrong with this fragment.

Edit: the same works fine when ported to **Python 3.4**, i.e. it doesn't stop the scraping when `nosleep = False`. Earlier was executing in **Python 2.7**.

```
def getOCdata(ed = '25FEB2016', start = 540*60, stop = 960*60, waitFlag = True, nosleep = True):
    ptime = datetime.now()
    while True:
        if (ptime.hour*60*60 + ptime.minute*60 + ptime.second) > stop:
            break
        else:
            try:
                ptime = datetime.now()
                scrapedata = pd.DataFrame(scrapefn(ed))
                scrapedata = scrapedata.ix[:, 1:21]
                scrapedata['timestamp'] = ptime
                scrapedata.to_csv(datafile, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
                if nosleep == False:
                    end = datetime.now()
                    tdiff = end-ptime
                    time.sleep(1 - (tdiff.seconds + tdiff.microseconds*1.0/10**6))
            except:
                continue
    return 0
```

Comment: You can simplify your code by moving the termination condition from the `if` to the `while` itself (negated).

Comment: @tobias_k The line `(ptime.hour*60*60 + ptime.minute*60 + ptime.second)` calculates amount of seconds elapsed since 12 AM, which is then compared against `stop` condition, i.e. if time is past 4 PM. Yeah the if could be moved to `while termination`.